# Show that an orthogonal group is a $ \frac{n(n−1)}2 $-dim. $ C^{\infty} $-Manifold and find its tangent space

Tags: real-analysis, lie-groups

The orthogonal group is defined as (with group structure inherited from $n\times n$ matrices)

$$O(n) := \{X\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n} : X^\text{t}X=I_n\}.$$

(i) Show that $O(n)$ is an $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$-dimensional $C^\infty$-manifold in the space of $n\times n$ matrices.

Hints. Exhibit $O(n)$ as the preimage of $0$ of the function $\phi$ from $n\times n$ matrices to the symmetric $n\times n$ matrices given by $X\mapsto X^\text{t}X − I_n$. (Note that the target space of $\phi$ is very important in order to satisfy the maximal rank condition.)

Then show that the equation $\phi'(A)H=S$ has a solution $H$ for each $A\in O(n)$ and each symmetric $n\times n$ matrix $S$. You will also need to compute the dimension of the space of symmetric $n\times n$ matrices.

(ii) Show that the tangent space $T_{I_n}O(n)$ at the identity is the space of antisymmetric matrices.

Comment: I get a vibe that a suitable theorem has been given in your course material, and the hints for question (i) are leading up to that. Since I don't know the theorem in question, I'm unsure what to suggest. I would approach it differently: the first row of $X$ can be any unit vector, i.e. a point on $S^{n-1}$. The second row can be any unit vector orthogonal to the first row, i.e. a point on $S^{n-2}$. Et cetera. This leads to a fibration and strongly suggests that the dimension is $(n-1)+(n-2)+\cdots+2+1=n(n-1)/2$.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

They've already given you the smooth map $\phi(X) = X^{t}X - I_n,$ and $O(n) = \phi^{-1} (0),$ so it is automatically a manifold (if the rank is constant). To see the dimension, you need to calculate the nullity of $\phi^{\prime}.$ See below for a full solution.

> The point here is that $\phi$ takes $n\times n$ matrices to symmetric matrices since $(X^{t}X- I)^t = X^{t}(X^{t})^{t} - I = X^t X - I.$ Take the directional derivative $\phi_v (X) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{(X+hv)^t(X+hv) - I - X^t X + I}{h} = X^t v + v^t X = (X^t v) + (X^t v)^t.$ That is, $\phi^{\prime}(X)$ takes $v$ to $(X^t v)+(X^t v)^t.$ Then we note that this is symmetric, and $\phi^{\prime}$ is onto the space of symmetric matrices since $X$ is invertible. The space of symmetric matrices has dimension $n(n+1)/2$ (you can do this yourself), whence the dimension of $O(n)$ is $n^2 - n(n+1)/2 = n(n-1)/2.$

To calculate the tangent space at $I$, you just want to look at $\phi^{\prime} (I)$ and calculate its null space.

Comment: I could not understand how you get the final answer of the directional derivative.....could u please explain it in details?

Comment: The derivative is a linear map which takes small deviations to the difference between the map before and after the deviation. If you write $XX^T$ and $(X+\nu)(X+\nu)^{T}=(X+\nu)(X^{T}+\nu^{T}) = XX^{T} + X \nu^{T} +\nu X^{T} + \nu \nu^{T}$, with $\nu \nu^{T}$ going to zero, then you have it.

Comment: Why the derivative is onto? hot yo i can get any Symetric matrix from X? thanks

Answer (score 0):

To show that the map $p\colon X\mapsto X^{t} \cdot X$ from $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ to $\mathcal{Sym}_n(\mathbb{R})$ is a submersion at $X= I$, it is enough to produce a section around $p(I) = I$, that is a map $s\colon U\to M_n(\mathbb{R})$ smooth, $s(I) = I$, and $p\circ s = Id$ on $U$ a neighborhood of $I$ in $\mathcal{Sym}_n(\mathbb{R})$. Take $s$ to be the [square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix), that is

$$s(I + \delta) = \sqrt{I+ \delta} = \sum_{k\ge 0} \binom{1/2}{k} \delta^k$$

Now to produce a section around any $X \in O(n, \mathbb{R})$, use the fact that $O(n)$ is a subgroup.