# Dimensions in group theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory

**Remark**. [My previous post about it](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4490530/on-the-understanding-of-dimensions-in-group-theory?noredirect=1&lq=1) has been linked to [a post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/383161/show-that-an-orthogonal-group-is-a-fracnn%E2%88%9212-dim-c-infty-manifo?noredirect=1&lq=1) that apparently solves my problem -- yet, said post does not satisfy me. I haven't learned the techniques used in my class.

As a physics student, I am currently learning about group theory. I have trouble understanding how to find the dimension of a (sub)group.

Let us consider the **orthogonal group $O(n)$**. Before talking about its dimension, one needs to show that $O(n)$ is indeed a group. We assume throughout that $O(n)\subset GL(n,\mathbb{R})$. A matrix is said to be orthogonal whenever it preserves the Euclidian norm - that is if
\begin{equation}
x^Ty = \left(Mx\right)^T\left(My\right) = x^TM^TMx
\end{equation}
This equation holds true *if and only if* $M^TM = Id$.

**Closure**. Let $A,B\in O(n)$. Let $C = AB$.
\begin{equation}
C^TC = (AB)^T(AB) = B^TA^TAB = B^TB = Id.
\end{equation}
**Identity**. One easily sees that $Id^T = Id$, such that $Id^T Id = Id$.

**Inverse**. Because $O(n)\subset GL(n,\mathbb{R})$, every $F\in O(n)\subset GL(n,\mathbb{R})$, is non-singular. Therefore $F^{-1}$ exists. Let us show that $F^{-1}\in O(n)$.
\begin{equation}
(F^{-1})^TF^{-1} = (F^T)^{-1}F^{-1} = (F^TF)^{-1} = Id.
\end{equation}
**Associativity**. Matrix multiplication being associative, any two matrices that happen to be a members of $O(n)$ will still be associative.

We now know for sure that $O(n)$ is a group. In fact, we even know that it is a subgroup of $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$. Now, how does one work out the dimension of that group? Here is how I tried to solve that problem.

Let $K\in O(n)$. For $n=2$, I find 3 conditions on the matrix elements of $K$. For $n=3$, I find 6 such conditions. We know that for a general matrix in $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$, the dimension is $n^2$. Hence, the dimension of $O(2)$ should be 2^2-3 = 1. Equivalently, for $O(3)$ one finds that the dimensions should be $9-6=3$. How does one find out from this that the dimension of $O(n)$ follows $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$?

Comment: Well, you can't conclude the general formula from just two examples. Is there something in the linked post you don't follow?

Comment: Also, dimension isn't a group-theoretic concept, it's a topological concept. Verifying the group axioms here doesn't establish that the set has a well-defined dimension.

Comment: As Karl said, dimension is not a purely group theoretic concept. However in this case you are working with Lie groups so there is a notion of dimension. If you want more information look into Lie groups and manifolds, but our goal is to find the dimensionality of the tangent space, you should be able to find that in this case by considering elements of the form $\exp(At)$ in $O(n)$ and then taking the derivative of $\exp(At) \exp(At)^T=I$ at $t=0$ to conclude that $A+A^T=0$, i.e. $A$ is any antisymmetric matrix. Then just find the dimension of the vector space of antisymmetric matrices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both sides of $AA^t=I$ are symmetric matrices.   What's the dimension of the symmetric matrices,  where of course you mean the dimension as a vector space (actually the dimension of the Lie Algebra of the Lie group)?  It's $n(n+1)/2$.  So, that's how many equations we get from the above matrix equation. Since $M_n$ has dimension $n^2$, we get $$n^2-n(n+1)/2=n(n-1)/2$$ for $O(n)$.