# Proving $\dim\{B\in {\rm M}(n,\mathbb{R}):BA^T=-AB^T\}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ where $A\in {\rm O}(n)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I'm reading Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds and trying to show that
$$T_A {\rm O}(n)=\{B\in {\rm M}(n,\mathbb{R}):BA^T=-AB^T\}.$$

**Here is my attempt about this question:**

Take any smooth curve $\gamma(t)$ in ${\rm O}(n)$ satisfying $\gamma(0)=A$, then
$$\gamma(t)\cdot\gamma(t)^T=I_n.$$
By taking the derivative of the above formula with respect to $t$, we can get
$$\gamma'(t)\cdot\gamma(t)^T+\gamma(t)\cdot(\gamma(t)^T)'=0,$$
then
$$\gamma'(0)\cdot\gamma(0)^T=-\gamma(0)\cdot(\gamma(t)^T)'|_{t=0}=-\gamma(0)\cdot\gamma'(0)^T.$$
Since $\gamma(0)=A$, we obtain that $\gamma'(0)$ satisfies
$$\gamma'(0)\cdot A^T=-A\cdot\gamma'(0)^T,$$
and $\gamma'(0)\in T_A {\rm O}(n)$ is arbitrary, therefore
$$T_A {\rm O}(n)\subset\{B\in {\rm M}(n,\mathbb{R}):BA^T=-AB^T\}.$$

Now it suffices to prove that
$$\dim\{B\in {\rm M}(n,\mathbb{R}):BA^T=-(BA^T)^T\}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$
where $A\in {\rm O}(n)$, because $\dim T_A {\rm O}(n)=\dim{\rm O}(n)=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$, but I'm stuck here.

I know that the dimension of the vector space composed of all skew-symmetric matrices is $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$, and the above set is very similar to the vector space composed of all skew-symmetric matrices in form, but I don't know what the connection between them is and how to connect them. Any help would be great appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that an orthogonal group is a $ \frac{n(n−1)}2 $-dim. $ C^{\infty} $-Manifold and find its tangent space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/383161/show-that-an-orthogonal-group-is-a-fracnn%e2%88%9212-dim-c-infty-manifo) $O(n)=\phi^{-1}(\{0\})$ where $\phi(X) = X^{t}X - I_n,$ hence $T_AO(n)=\ker(\phi'(A)).$

Comment: The problem you provided only shows the form of $T_{I_n} {\rm O}(n)$.

Comment: No, it is a true duplicate because in the accepted answer, $T_{I_n}$ is mentionned as an example but the method indicated works for any $T_A.$

Comment: Yes, I understand it. Thank you for your providing!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While there
is a comprehensive answer referenced in the comment by Anne Bauval, there is also a simple direct answer to your question: Let $A \in O(n)$ and define
$$S_A :=\{B\in {\rm M}(n,\mathbb{R}):BA^T=-AB^T\}.$$
Then $B \in S_A$ iff $BA^T$ is skew-symmetric.
Since $A^T$ is invertible, the map $B \mapsto BA^T$ preserves dimension.

Comment: You mean that the map $B \mapsto BA^T$ can establish the vector space isomorphism between the vector space composed of all skew-symmetric matrices and $S_A$, so the dimensions are equal.

Comment: @HeraZhang001 Exactly.